# Genetic algorithm Solution - Pareto

Tags: mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, genetic, pareto-chart

I'm implementing a genetic algorithm (NSGA2) in Scala. It is already developed and I was now testing. I used the SCH problem with n=1 (Problem Size). I think I got the right solution but with something that I consider weird. I know that the solution to this problem is [0,2]. I get most of the solutions in this interval, but some solutions are outside this interval (and have a non zero rank). I already increased the number of generations, but yield the same result.

So I use a Population of 500, and about 400 genomes are correct, but the last 100 are outside the correct interval [0,2] (And rank different of 0).

So the solution that I get is this:

[image: Complete solution of NSGA2]

If erase the last solutions (around 100) that I know are wrong (outside of [0,2]) I get the right Pareto frotier.:

[image: Solution of NSGA2 with wrong solutions erased]

Is this normal, or this indicates that is something wrong with my code?

Comment: If you have solutions outside of your feasible interval then there must be a problem somewhere in your code.

Comment: I'm new to Genetic algorithms, but I think these solutions are not outside the feasible interval (i define that the optimization variable can be between -10 and 10). And the solutions that I'm referring to are inside this interval. But not inside the interval that I know is the right solution to the problem ([0,2]).

I want to know if makes sense the final population has genomes that are outside the optimal solution (rank != 0)

Comment: I understand what you mean now. GAs offer no proof of optimality, so it is very possible that your population has not converged to the optimal solution. That is not unusual.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But what I think is weird is the fact that most of the individuals in the last population are correct, but something like 20% of the last population is wrong. Can I just delete the ones that I know are incorrect or is that something that I must not do? I think this is a simple problem, so the GA should get the optimal solution no?

Comment: If it's not a hybrid GA, then it involves no hill-climbing, so there is indeed no guarantee of solution optimality for _any_ problem as mentioned by @philippe-olivier. And any generation can contain worse solutions, just because (even with elitism) it's populated with stochastic operators (mutation, crossover). Don't you want to analyze only the best rated solutions (above average, top 10%, etc.) from the final population?